# FluentValidation - Validating a View Model that contains a list of an Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

I am trying out FluentValidation on a project that contains complex view models and I read the [documentation here](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#ReusingValidators) but I don't see how to set up the rules to validate a list of objects declared in my view model. In my example below, the list in the view model contains 1 or more Guitar objects. Thanks

**View Model**

```
 [FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(CustomerViewModelValidator))]
    public class CustomerViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Phone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public List<Guitar> Guitars { get; set; } 
    }
```

**Guitar class used in View Model**

```
public class Guitar
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int? ProductionYear { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model Validator Class**

```
 public class CustomerViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomerViewModel>
    {


        public CustomerViewModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotNull();
            RuleFor(x => x.LastName).NotNull();
            RuleFor(x => x.Phone).NotNull();
            RuleFor(x => x.EmailAddress).NotNull();
           //Expects an indexed list of Guitars here????


        }
    }
```

Comment: Cant u have separete Validator for Guitar class?. What kind of validation u want on Ilist, is it to have more than one element?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You would add this to your CustomerViewModelValidator

```
RuleFor(x => x.Guitars).SetCollectionValidator(new GuitarValidator());
```

So your CustomerViewModelValidator would look like this:

```
public class CustomerViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomerViewModel>
{
    public CustomerViewModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.LastName).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Phone).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.EmailAddress).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Guitars).SetCollectionValidator(new GuitarValidator());
    }
}
```

Add the GuitarValidator would look something like:

```
public class GuitarValidator : AbstractValidator<Guitar>
{
    public GuitarValidator()
    {
        // All your other validation rules for Guitar. eg.
        RuleFor(x => x.Make).NotNull();
    }
 }
```

Comment: SetCollectionValidator has been deprecated, use RuleForEach now.

Comment: Syntax for RuleForEach(x => x.Guitars).SetValidator(new GuitarValidator()); ref answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53227565/193061

Answer (score 86):

This code deprecated: `RuleFor(x => x.Guitars).SetCollectionValidator(new GuitarValidator());`

This is new:

```
RuleForEach(x => x.Guitars).SetValidator(new GuitarValidator());
```

Comment: This is very interesting

Answer (score 3):

```
RuleForEach(
  itemToValidate => 
     new YourObjectValidator());


public class YourObjectValidator : AbstractValidator<YourObject>
{
  public EdgeAPIAddressValidator()
  {
     RuleFor(r => r.YourProperty)
         .MaximumLenght(100);
  }
}
```

Comment: Although this code snippet may answer the question, including an explanation of *why* and *how* it helps solve the problem improves the quality and longevity of your answer, especially regarding older questions like this one. See ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

You can use childrule

```
RuleForEach(p => p.Guitars).ChildRules(child =>{
child.RuleFor(x=>x.Make).NotEmpty().WithMessage({PropertyName}required.") .NotNull(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

It works with the latest version of Fluent
and contains a complete example to be used.

The code in the answer it's deprecated.